# Ошибка после разрешения на запись андроид

Tags: java, android, permissions

Есть код:

```
    import android.Manifest;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics;
    import tanat.androidtesttask.R;
    import tanat.androidtesttask.errorreporter.GetLogs;
    import tanat.androidtesttask.utils.LoadLocalData;
    import tanat.androidtesttask.utils.SendEMail;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        private FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;
        public Context context;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            // Obtain the FirebaseAnalytics instance.
            mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);

            context = MainActivity.this;
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
            return true;
        }

        public String LOG_FILE_NAME = "logs";

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            String action = "";

            int i = item.getItemId();
            //
            if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {

            if (i == R.id.save_logs) {
                    if (isCheckPermission(1)) {
                        saveLogs();
                    }
            } else if (i == R.id.send_logs) {
                if (isCheckPermission(2)) {
                    new SendEMail(MainActivity.this).send(LOG_FILE_NAME);
                    tanat.androidtesttask.errorreporter.Log.d("Permission granted, file sending");
                } else {
    ///
                }
            }
            } else {
                action = "Insert a memory card";
            }
            Toast.makeText(this, action, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        private boolean isCheckPermission(int i) {
            if (i == 1) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) !=
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // Should we show an explanation?
                    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                        showMessageOKCancel("Requires write permission to save logs to file");
                        return false;
                    }

                    // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                            PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);

                    return false;
                    // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST is an
                    // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
                    // result of the request.
                }
                return true;
            } else if (i == 2) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) !=
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // Should we show an explanation?
                    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                        showMessageOKCancel("Requires read permission to transfer file");
                        return false;
                    }
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                            PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);

                    return false;
                }

                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        private void showMessageOKCancel(String message) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .setMessage(message)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", listener)
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", listener)
                    .create()
                    .show();
        }

        final private int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST = 7;

        DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            final int BUTTON_NEGATIVE = -2;
            final int BUTTON_POSITIVE = -1;

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                switch (which) {
                    case BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                        // int which = -2
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        break;

                    case BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                        // int which = -1
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                                MainActivity.this, new String[]{
                                        android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                                        android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        break;
                }
            }
        };

    /*    Handler handler = new Handler(){
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg){
                LoadLocalData loadSD = new LoadLocalData(MainActivity.this);
                loadSD.writeFileSD(LOG_FILE_NAME, GetLogs.get());
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Logs save", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };*/

        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case PERMISSIONS_REQUEST: {
                    // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                    if (grantResults.length > 0
                            && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        // permission was granted!
if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Permission on write storage granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            saveLogs();
                        }
                        if (grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission on read storage granted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    } else {

                        // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                        // functionality that depends on this permission.
                    }
                    return;
                }

                // other 'case' lines to check for other
                // permissions this app might request.
            }
        }

//метод который сохраняет логи
        public void saveLogs (){
            LoadLocalData loadSD = new LoadLocalData(MainActivity.this);
            loadSD.writeFileSD(LOG_FILE_NAME, GetLogs.get());
            Toast.makeText(this, "Logs save", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
        //    Log.d("Logs","Logs: " + GetLogs.get());

            super.onDestroy();
        }
    }
```

При первой попытке сохранить логи спрашивает разрешения на запись данных на карту памяти, если его получает то ЗАПИСЫВАЕТ ФАЙЛ, после чего сразу валиться с ошибкой:

```
E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=7, result=-1, data=Intent { act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS (has extras) }} to activity {tanat.androidtesttask/tanat.androidtesttask.activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
                         at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3699)
                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742)
                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393)
                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                      Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
                         at tanat.androidtesttask.activity.MainActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(Unknown Source)
                         at android.app.Activity.dispatchRequestPermissionsResult(Activity.java:6553)
                         at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6432)
                         at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3695)
                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742) 
                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java) 
                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393) 
                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: tanat.androidtesttask, PID: 2022
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=7, result=-1, data=Intent { act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS (has extras) }} to activity {tanat.androidtesttask/tanat.androidtesttask.activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3699)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                   Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
                      at tanat.androidtesttask.activity.MainActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(Unknown Source)
                      at android.app.Activity.dispatchRequestPermissionsResult(Activity.java:6553)
                      at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6432)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3695)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

При последующих запусках (когда разрешение уже получено) проблем нет.
Если убрать метод сохранения данных, поставить просто тоаст - работает (точнее и так работает но с тоастом не выпадает). Читал что диалог пермишена вроде как в отдельном потоке, пробивал через хандер сохранять (хотя тоже бред, тоаст тогда б тоже не работал), безрезультатно.
Подскажите пожалуйста как решить проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем после долгий раздумий я понял.
Есть такой нюанс: если даешь permission на один элемент группы то срабатывает он на всю группу.
То есть когда я давал разрешение на запись данных в файл, так же давалось сразу и на чтение поэтому у меня в масиве grantResults был только 1 елемент, и при проверке второго приложение падало.
Изменил метод:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST){
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            saveLogs();
            if (sendMail) {
                new SendEMail(MainActivity.this).send(LOG_FILE_NAME);
                sendMail = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```